# Custom entity data handling in Symfony2 forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.6

I'm currently implementing notification preferences on a site using *Symfony 2.6*.

The entity that holds the notification preference is as follows:

```
class UserNotification
{
    //...
    
    /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
      */
    private $downtimeNotificationEnabled;

    /**
      * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
      */
    private $newPostNotificationEnabled;

    //...
}
```

There are currently about 15 different keys like this, but I would like now to also allow configuration of *Email*, *SMS* and *Dashboard* notifications for each type. Rather than create two additional columns for each type, I was thinking to change each `$*Enabled` column type from `boolean` to Doctrine `array`, and hold the data as an associative array (`['dashboard' => true, 'email' => false, 'sms' => true]`) within each table column.

My question is in regards to then hooking this `array` column into a Symonfy *Form* type. From what I understand, I can create a custom type for the field, and use this instead of the `'checkbox'` type I currently use. Something like this:

```
class NotificationSettingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('dashboard', 'checkbox', [
                'mapped'    => false,
                'data'      => true
            ])
            ->add('email', 'checkbox', [
                'mapped'    => false,
                'data'      => true
            ])
            ->add('sms', 'checkbox', [
                'mapped'    => false,
                'data'      => true
            ])
        ;
    }

    //...
}
```

...and the main form type...

```
class NotificationsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('downtimeNotificationEnabled', new NotificationSettingType())
            ->add('newPostNotificationEnabled', new NotificationSettingType())
            //...
        ;
    }
}
```

But then I don't understand how I can populate the values of the `'checkbox'` types in the `NotificationSettingType` with the `array` data from the entity.

## Edit 1

To further clarify:

I'm looking for how to bind the data from/to the columns in `UserNotification` specifically.

For example, say:

```
UserNotification::$downtimeNotificationEnabled = [
    'dashboard' => true, 
    'email'     => false, 
    'sms'       => true
]
```

Then in `NotificationSettingType` for this column:

- `'dashboard'` would be *checked*
- `'email'` would be *unchecked*
- `'sms'` would be *checked*

Then, after submitting, if I unchecked *SMS* for example, the new array would be in the column variable as:

```
UserNotification::$downtimeNotificationEnabled = [
    'dashboard' => true, 
    'email'     => false, 
    'sms'       => false
]
```

I know how to pass options but I don't know how to transform this data to make it compatible with the Symfony2 form types.

Comment: What you want to do is to add a FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA event to your NotificationSettingType.  This will allow checking your check boxes based on data inside of your UserNotification entity. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: And while a bit off topic, if you have 15+ boolean columns then you really should consider using a OneToMany relation between User and UserNotification.  As it stands right now, you won't be able to add additional notifications without changing your entity.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look but why is this a comment not an answer? Also, to add additional notifications it requires code changes anyway, as those notifications need to be implemented. A one to many provides no benefits that I can see, and makes the code more complicated.

Comment: Too lazy to write up a real answer.  As far as the relation goes, it was just a suggestion.  I would start with an configuration array for defining the notifications.  Once implemented, additional ones could be added by adjusting the configuration.  Bit a more work upfront perhaps but might save a bunch of boiler plate code.  Again, just a suggestion.